# Unexpected text at the bottom of posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

For whatever reason, the text `H433895296H` was appended to my [tag wiki suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177) for [flag-badges](/questions/tagged/flag-badges).  It doesn't appear in the markdown.

Here's what the markdown for the suggestion is:

```markdown
Flag badges are badges awarded for having a specific number of helpful flags and consist of [![Citizen Patrol][Citizen Patrol Image]][Citizen Patrol Link] (1 helpful flag), [![Deputy][Deputy Image]][Deputy Link] (80 helpful flags), and [![Marshal][Marshal Image]][Marshal Link] (500 helpful flags).


<!-- links to badge page -->
  [Citizen Patrol Link]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol
  [Deputy Link]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy
  [Marshal Link]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal

<!-- images of badges -->

  [Citizen Patrol Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fffM.png "Citizen Patrol"
  [Deputy Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxERU.png "Deputy"
  [Marshal Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY3Ng.png "Marshal"
```

And here's the expected rendered output (as it appears normally in posts):

> Flag badges are badges awarded for having a specific number of helpful flags and consist of [image: Citizen Patrol] (1 helpful flag), [image: Deputy] (80 helpful flags), and [image: Marshal] (500 helpful flags).

But I'm getting this instead:

> Flag badges are badges awarded for having a specific number of helpful flags and consist of [image: Citizen Patrol] (1 helpful flag), [image: Deputy] (80 helpful flags), and [image: Marshal] (500 helpful flags).
>
> H433895296H

Here's images of this as well: <sub>(Note that when these were taken, imgur was blocked and as such, the images didn't display.  They would display normally had imgur been available)</sub>

<kbd>[image: Rendered output on the wiki page]</kbd>
<kbd>[image: Markdown text in the editor.]</kbd>
<kbd>[image: Rendered output in the suggestion]</kbd>
<kbd>[image: Markdown text in the suggestion page]</kbd>

Where is this text coming from?  I'm assuming it is a bug.

EDIT: It's also appearing at the bottom of this post; it's not in the markdown here either.  (I do have the same markdown from that post in here for the purpose of the expected output).  Right below this text, in fact.

Comment: *H433895296H* at the end of your post. Is this also intended?

Comment: That *looks* like a hash that Markdown creates when it pulls out a block of something and needs to place it back in at a later time. Might be related to the fact that you're using an HTML comment to separate two blocks of content that get removed.

Comment: @Compass Nope.  Wow, happened here as well.

Comment: @Pokechu22, take a look at [my edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/277023/4). Seems that there was some stuff left over at the end. I'm not sure if this was intentional or not though. Feel free to rollback if not.

Comment: @gunr2171 It looks like those links at the bottom *were* the problem here. But you also broke all the images in the blockquotes by completely removing them.

Comment: @animuson, I see, and I didn't notice I caused harm. Rolling back.

Comment: @gunr2171 The links at the bottom were for the images in the blockquotes.  But they also are probably the cause of the text.

Comment: got a repro, looking into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fixed now](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=5ced64e1fb38ab0f7b9940bc99abaf5dc2a8ae9e). As you can see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/277023/8) (that page is rendered on-demand, not cached), re-rendering this question (by making any edit) would no longer create the extraneous content.

Comment: Why am I still seeing `H433895296H` at the bottom of the question if the issue has been fixed?

Comment: @Joehot200 See the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: For an example of it being successfully removed look at the [tag wiki edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2177), which has been changed properly.  (Compared to the version in [the screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rz8XN.png)).